# sql query expression

Tags: sql

[The table retrieves data from the table "Group" with 2 columns First key "GroupNumber" and GroupName"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W0oT.png)I am trying to create a sql query in Microsoft Access from a table with two columns that will works as below:
Based on the user's selection from the first column the query has to return the value of the second column, and based on the user's selection from the second column the query has to return the value of the first.

Any idea how is possible to express the user's selection in sql? Ty

Comment: Please show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some more data would be useful. AT this moment, it is hard to understand what it is exactly you are trying to do.

However, you mention two different selecting actions that need to be done by the user, so two SELECT statements would work.
To return the value of the second column based on user selection of the first: SELECT second_column_value FROM table WHERE first_column_value = value_selected_by_user
To return the value of the first column based on user selection of the second:SELECT first_column_value FROM table WHERE second_column_value = value_selected_by_user

or you can use drop-down lists, if the situation allows

Try providing more data to get more useful answers.